# Laravel language change

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I worked with laravel language english and bangla. Few days ago it's worked fine but now it's not working. here is my app.php.

```
<?php

return [
    'name' => 'Laravel',
    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'locale' => 'bl',
    'fallback_locale' => 'en', 
    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

?>
```

Comment: need more details...

Comment: Can you show us the `lang` folder in your `resources` folder?

Comment: I've fixed code-formatting because your code was invisible

Comment: Thanks @ThomasFritsch

Comment: In lang folder there has 'bl'  folder for bangla language, 'en' folder for English language. i use this format  {{ trans('sattendance_lang.panel_title') }}  @GabMic

Answer (score 0):

I write a very simple middleware that sets the lang of the browser:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class Language
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        App::setLocale(explode('-', explode(',', Request::server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'))[0])[0]);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And register in Kernel.php:

```
protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
```

If you want the user to change the language, see [Laravel localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655930/laravel-localization)